# User Cannot Be Found when page is Checked In or Published due to People Picker column

Tags: permissions, people-picker

We just deployed a new site collection. News pages have an author/people picker column built into the page template. All SP users have access to the site via user group but a 'User Cannot Be Found' error is returned when attempting to check in or publish a page with a user from the All SP users group. The people picker column does not return an 'User Cannot Be Found' if the user is individually granted access to the site though.